# Pass object into function as parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In C/C++ I know we had pointers to objects and arrays, so they could be passed into function parameters without the need to clone said objects and arrays. In Javascript there's no such option, so we just use the object variable.

Is this good practise?

```js
function setWhite(obj){
  obj.color = "white";
}

var shirt = {
  color: "red",
  size: "L"
}

setWhite(shirt);

console.log(shirt);
```

Comment: You are not cloning anything. You just pass a reference to your object by value.

Comment: `But is it ok to do this?` it doesn't throw an error, so the answer is "yes". `Is it good practise?` it depends. A lot of times mutating an object leads to unnecessary complexity. Then agian, a lot of times it's fine to do it as it simplifies things. So clearly...there is no clear answer to this.

Comment: As a side note, I think you mean to say "pass objects", not "parse objects". Parsing is like taking apart and understanding data. Reading through and understanding it. Passing is the term you use to give data to a function.

Comment: @JakeT., corrected accordingly

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira missed one in the body of the question. It's a nit picky thing to point out, but then again, compilers are very nit picky, too haha. And it can be difficult to look up a question without the right words.

Comment: @vlaz, a defined number of commands are correct according to certain JS/ES versions and/or do not throw errors in certain browsers; and though such commands may not be according to other JS/ES versions and throw errors in other browsers, respectively. Thus, not "throwing an error" may mean nothing.

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira but this behaviour has been within JS since the start. Besides, my point was that your question makes very little sense, as there is no objective measure here. The behaviour is what it is - it can be misused, it could be leveraged to good effect. It's a bit like asking whether it's good practice adding numbers together.

Comment: @vlaz, ok ok, I'm just saying that "it doesn't throw an error" doesn't mean a lot in many circumstances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In javascript, objects are passed by reference. So, if you change the value of an object within the function, it changes it back outside of the function.

If you did something like this, though, it wouldn't be the case:

```
function setWhite(obj){
  obj = {
    color: "white",
    size: "M"
  }
}

var shirt = {
  color: "red",
  size: "L"
}

setWhite(shirt);

console.log(shirt); // shirt will remain red / L
```

Note the difference is that I'm reassigning `obj` inside the `setWhite()` method, so the original obj is lost to that function.

This is an important concept to understand, since it can have disturbing and unintended consequences if you let it slip your mind, accidentally changing the value on objects that you didn't want to change, just temporarily manipulate the data for some other purpose. It's especially important to keep in mind when you start working with async functions. Async functions happen in the background, and you have to specify when to 'await' for them. If you call an async function expecting it to change your objects values, but don't await it, your object might not have the updated values yet when you go to use them later in the code that calls the async function.

Similarly, if you call an async function, but don't await it, and later change the object that was passed in, by the time the async function goes to use the values from that object, they could be different than you intended when you called it.

Comment: "*objects are passed by reference*" - or even simpler, *objects are references*

Comment: @Bergi is more technically correct. I chose the language I did because it's the terminology used coming from C/C++, but if that's not an appropriate choice I won't be offended by an edit.

Comment: @JakeT. thanks; but why exactly in your example "the original obj is lost"? I suppose because another _new reference_ is created inside the function. Is that correct?  A new reference is created when you type literally `{};`

Comment: Yes, when I do `obj = ...` inside `setWhite()`, it forgets the old reference, and creates a reference to that new object. The old `shirt` still exists, though, since the variable outside of the function is still holding the reference. But, when you assign within the function, the outside variable isn't affected. You have to assign to the *properties* of an object to change them.

Comment: Something you could also do is add a function property to the shirt object itself. Within the `{}`s, add a line for `setWhite: () => { this.color = "white"; }`.  Then you can call `shirt.setWhite()` if you wanted to change it white. You could also do something like add the property `setColor: (newColor) => { this.color = newColor }`, then call `shirt.setColor('white');`

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira This is beyond the scope of your question, and may be a lot to digest if you're learning fundamentals, but you'll see some combination of all of these implementation methods if you're looking at other people's source code, so it's important to understand them all.